# Numerically stable hyperbolic tangent

Tags: pytorch, activation-function

The hyperbolic tangent is commonly used as an activation function:
$$
tanh(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}
$$
Although, it is unclear how this function is implemented to be numerically stable in frameworks like pytorch or numpy. Since $e^x$ will explode for any $x \gtrapprox 1000$, is the function being approximated in some way? Or are there static checks for big input numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Commonly you divide the domain up into different accuracy,stability regimes and apply a different approximation within each.

For $|x|<1$ you can use a polynomial approximation, like Chebyshev. For $1<|x|\leq E$, $E$ depending on implementation of the formula, you can use a related formula to the one you described.

For $|x|>E$ you can use $\tanh(x) \approx sign(x).$

More details [here](https://www.nag.com/numeric/nl/nagdoc_latest/clhtml/s/s10aac.html) from a documented implementation.

Comment: Thanks, using 64-bit floats I expect $E$ to be equal to the natural logarithm of the max value representation of a 64-bit float? ```np.log(np.finfo(np.float64).max)```